# How can I run a .RMD (Rmarkdown) file in bash script?

Tags: r, bash, r-markdown

Maybe this is a stupid question, but I couldn't find an answer and
I'm newbie using r-markdown.

I created a script in R for some statistical calculations and  graphics. After finishing the script, my tutor told me it would be right that R script generates a report in pdf.

I tried to export the result with different methods inside .R file but finally I discovered that the best way to create a report was r-markdonw.

However, this R-script is to be used in a bash file to automate the process... Example:

1. Java program generates files
2. R script takes these files and do some statistical calculations.
3. Generate a clear report in pdf or html.

My question is... How can I run a .RMD file in bash script ?

Edit:

```
Error: pandoc version 1.12.3 or higher is required and was not found (see the help page ?rmarkdown::pandoc_a
```

Comment: `Rscript -e 'rmarkdown::render(…)'`

Comment: @hrbrmstr, please post as answer (or find a duplicate - there might be one out there ...)

Comment: I'm gd with that as a dup

Comment: @hrbrmstr I did what you said me and --> `Error: pandoc version 1.12.3 or higher is required and was not found (see the help page ?rmarkdown::pandoc_available).`

Comment: Well, you need to install pandoc then.

Comment: @hrbrmstr Is there any way to don't install pandoc? I will use this script in a server by ssh connection and probably I'll not able to install pandoc there.

Comment: Then you can't generate the report. pandoc is a first-order requirement for knitting R markdown documents. RStudio bring pandoc along with it, so why not just extract the pandoc binary from the linux build (assuming this is a linux server) and copy it over. You obviously have R packages installed on the server, so I'm not sure why this would be something you can't also install.